# add UserDetails to SecurityContextHolder

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

How to manually authenticate user by adding ManualUserDetails extends `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails`  into SecurityContextHolder.setAuthentication(..) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have created a custom authentication provider (called myAuthenticationProvider below)  as follows:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref='myAuthenticationProvider'/>
</authentication-manager>
```

In the bean myAuthenticationProvider you need to provide a userDetails service, that would load the your ManualUserDetails.

Answer (score 1):

As Umesh mentioned - you should provide your own authentication provider and override method

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
```

This function should return an object that implements interface UserDetails.